How to interpret the geometry of NO2 using VSEPR and orbital hybridization?
I was given to study the structure of $\ce{NO2}$ using VSEPR theory, even if the presence of a single electron is better explained by MO theory. Using the standard form $\ce{AX_nE_m}$, where $\ce{A}$ stands for the central atom, $\ce{X}$ the terminal ones and $\ce{E}$ stands for free electron pairs, how can this be written in the case of $\ce{NO2}$ (or any other molecule with an odd number of electrons for this matter)? Is it $\ce{AX_2E_{1/2}}$ or $\ce{AX_2E_1}$ or, as I've seen written on the internet $\ce{AX_2E}$? And why?
And since one way to determine the hybridization of the orbitals of the central atom is to check the geometry of the molecules (and the steric number), should $\ce{N}$ in $\ce{NO2}$ be considered hybridized to $\ce{sp}$ or $\ce{sp^2}$? And why?

NO2 is sp2 hybridized. The best guidance I can find is that NO2 would be AX2E1/2. Since 1 electron counts as a half an electron pair. When determining hybridization and geometry, you generally count the half-pair as a pair, since it is including another orbital. NO2 is definitely bent, not linear. There are some exceptions, though, for example methyl radical is planar. I'm not 100% sure of this answer - you should probably ask the professor who told you to study this.
